# How to duplicate an estimator in order to use it on multiple data sets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is an example that creates two data sets:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# data set 1
X1, y1 = make_classification(n_classes=2, n_features=5, random_state=1)
# data set 2
X2, y2 = make_classification(n_classes=2, n_features=5, random_state=2)
```

I want to use the `LogisticRegression` estimator with the same parameter values to fit a classifier on each data set:

```
lr = LogisticRegression()

clf1 = lr.fit(X1, y1)
clf2 = lr.fit(X2, y2)

print "Classifier for data set 1: "
print "  - intercept: ", clf1.intercept_
print "  - coef_: ", clf1.coef_

print "Classifier for data set 2: "
print "  - intercept: ", clf2.intercept_
print "  - coef_: ", clf2.coef_
```

The problem is that both classifiers are the same:

```
Classifier for data set 1: 
  - intercept:  [ 0.05191729]
  - coef_:  [[ 0.06704494  0.00137751 -0.12453698 -0.05999127  0.05798146]]
Classifier for data set 2: 
  - intercept:  [ 0.05191729]
  - coef_:  [[ 0.06704494  0.00137751 -0.12453698 -0.05999127  0.05798146]]
```

For this simple example, I could use something like:

```
lr1 = LogisticRegression()
lr2 = LogisticRegression()

clf1 = lr1.fit(X1, y1)
clf2 = lr2.fit(X2, y2)
```

to avoid the problem. However, the question remains: How to duplicate / copy an estimator with its particular parameter values in general?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
from sklearn.base import clone

lr1 = LogisticRegression()
lr2 = clone(lr1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that because sklearn.base is not documented in the reference: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/classes.html

Comment: I guess that is because they are considered internal. I guess clone should be documented, though...

Comment: When looping over estimators in a list, Python iteration yields a copy of the estimator in the list (rather than a reference), is it still necessary to clone the estimator in this case? Any dangers of not cloning it in such a setting?

Comment: Just note that, if you want to duplicate a "trained" model, use `deepcopy`, `clone` doesn't preserve any "trained" parameters.

Comment: @mloning Could you elaborate or provide code for when a copy of an estimator is made as a result of looping through a list?